# Issue in Grouping row collapsed and expansion in jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have implemented my JQgrid Grouping rows collaped as in wesite 'http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html'. When page loads,it collapse all groping data so that user can expand the group and check the content.

In my case, table is not showing treeview button to expand or collapse.I am not getting how to expand the collapsed rows. Please give me some solution

Here I have put my code also.

```
var grid_selector = "#grid-table";
var pager_selector = "#grid-pager";

var mydata = [ {id:"1",invdate:"2010-05-24",name:"test",note:"note",tax:"10.00",total:"2111.00"} , 
            {id:"2",invdate:"2010-05-25",name:"test2",note:"note2",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"}, 
            {id:"3",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"}, 
            {id:"4",invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"test",note:"note",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
            {id:"5",invdate:"2007-10-05",name:"test2",note:"note2",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
            {id:"6",invdate:"2007-09-06",name:"test3",note:"note3",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"},
            {id:"7",invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"test",note:"note",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"}, 
            {id:"8",invdate:"2007-10-03",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"21.00",total:"320.00"}, 
            {id:"9",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"}, 
            {id:"11",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"}, 
            {id:"12",invdate:"2007-10-02",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"}, 
            {id:"13",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"}, 
            {id:"14",invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
            {id:"15",invdate:"2007-10-05",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"}, 
            {id:"16",invdate:"2007-09-06",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"}, 
            {id:"17",invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"}, 
            {id:"18",invdate:"2007-10-03",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
            {id:"19",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"}, 
            {id:"21",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"}, 
            {id:"22",invdate:"2007-10-02",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"}, 
            {id:"23",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"}, 
            {id:"24",invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
            {id:"25",invdate:"2007-10-05",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"}, 
            {id:"26",invdate:"2007-09-06",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"},
            {id:"27",invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
            {id:"28",invdate:"2007-10-03",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
            {id:"29",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"} ]; 


jQuery(grid_selector).jqGrid({ 
        data: mydata, 
        datatype: "local", 
        height: 'auto', rowNum: 30,
        rowList: [10,20,30], 
        colNames:['Inv No','Date', 'Client', 'Amount','Tax','Total','Notes'], 
        colModel:[ {name:'id',index:'id', width:60, sorttype:"int"}, 
        {name:'invdate',index:'invdate', width:90, sorttype:"date", formatter:"date"},
        {name:'name',index:'name', width:100, editable:true}, 
        {name:'amount',index:'amount', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float", formatter:"number", editable:true}, 
        {name:'tax',index:'tax', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float", editable:true}, 
        {name:'total',index:'total', width:80,align:"right",sorttype:"float"}, 
        {name:'note',index:'note', width:150, sortable:false} ], 


pager: pager_selector, 
viewrecords: true, 
sortname: 'name', 
grouping:true, 
groupingView : { groupField : ['name'], groupColumnShow : [true], 
groupText : ['<b>{0} - {1} Item(s)</b>'],
groupCollapse : true, 
groupOrder: ['desc'] }, 
caption: "Initially hidden data" 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I can't reproduce the problem. [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/user2955338.htm) works.

Comment: Is there is any dependency with JQgrid version or do I need to include any javascript libraries to get treeview buttons ????? I am using jqGrid  4.5.2 version

Comment: @user2955338: jqGrid need just jQuery.js and jQuery UI css (see the source code of my demo or [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:first_grid#html_file))